# Passing credentials for authentication to C# ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have setup an ASP.NET Web API. I want to dynamically validate the basic authentication provided (username and web access key) in the header and pass it to the network credentials method I have setup to validate details.

This is my model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string No_;
    public string Name;
    public string AccountingLocation;
}
```

My controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{
    try
    {
            ws.ValidationRegWebService();
            Validation.Customer customerVal = new Validation.Customer();
            customerVal = ws.validationReg_ws.Read(id);
            [...]
     }
     [...]
 }
```

My network credential method:

```
public NetworkCredential Credential() 
{
   NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential
   {
         UserName = globals.UserName,
         Password = globals.Password
    };
    return cred;
}
```

[image: Postman Authorization]

How can I pass the authorization details from the client to the network credential method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method, you can get the basic auth header sent by postman like this:

```
var header = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
if(header == null) throw UnauthorizedException(); // Not sure this exception exists I just made it up
```

Then decode it, as it simply contains username:password encoded in base64 prefixed with "Basic ":

```
var encodedValue = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim(); // Now just a b64 string
var decodedValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedValue));
var values = decodedValue.Split(":");

var username = values[0];
var password = values[1];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I had to  exclude the FirstOrDefault() method in the header variable to be able to access the Substring method. Thanks. Appreciate